# Using BEFORE UPDATE ON to update a column value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table as described below, and am using BEFORE INSERT triggers to update a column's value to a session defined variable.  The INSERT set's the modified_by_user and created_by_user columns both to 1 as expected.  The UPDATE, however, does not change modified_by_user to 2 as I expected, but leaves it at 1.  How can BEFORE UPDATE ON be used to update a column value?  I am using MySQL 5.5.  Thanks

```
SET @users_id=1;
INSERT INTO notes(notes,record_status_id,date_created) VALUES("hello","active",NOW());
//modified_by_user=1, created_by_user=1, notes="hello"

SET @users_id=2;
UPDATE notes SET notes="goodby" WHERE id=1;
//modified_by_user=1, created_by_user=1, notes="goodby"

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notes` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `notes` TEXT NULL ,
  `record_status_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
  `modified_by_user` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `created_by_user` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_notes_users1_idx` (`modified_by_user` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_notes_users2_idx` (`created_by_user` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_notes_record_status1_idx` (`record_status_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_notes_users10`
    FOREIGN KEY (`modified_by_user` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_notes_users20`
    FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_user` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_notes_record_status1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`record_status_id` )
    REFERENCES `record_status` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DELIMITER $$


CREATE TRIGGER tg_notes_ins BEFORE INSERT ON notes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.created_by_user IS NULL OR NEW.created_by_user = '' THEN
        SET NEW.created_by_user = @users_id;
        SET NEW.modified_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
END$$



CREATE TRIGGER tg_notes_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON notes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.modified_by_user IS NULL OR NEW.modified_by_user = '' THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think you want an AFTER UPDATE trigger in order to use the NEW alias.

Comment: @SomeSillyName.  If I use AFTER UPDATE, will I not need a UPDATE in the trigger, and will it not trigger another trigger?  Also, it does work with the INSERT using BEFORE, and I would think they would be similar.

Comment: You are right. It should be BEFORE UPDATE. But if the insert is setting the modified_by_user value it will never be NULL or '' which you are testing for in your BEFORE UPDATE trigger.

Comment: @SomeSillyName.  That was my intention.  If the query doesn't include a value to insert, then the trigger sees that it isn't set and uses the session variable.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: If I get rid of the constraint `IF NEW.modified_by_user IS NULL OR NEW.modified_by_user = '' THEN ... END IF;` then it will update to @user_id, however, it will do so regardless of whether the query includes a value to set modified_by_user.

Comment: The following appears to work `CREATE TRIGGER tg_notes_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON notes
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.modified_by_user = OLD.modified_by_user THEN
        SET NEW.modified_by_user = @users_id;
    END IF;
END`

Answer (score 1):

On an UPDATE, if the query doesn't specify a value for a given column NEW.column is not NULL as I originally expected, but is the value of that column should it not be changing (i.e. the previous OLD.column value)